# boot time grub menu and splash screen customization

Tags: boot, grub2, customization

I want to customize the boot time grub menu and splash screen for a livecd.

Comment: Hi, for which 0S??

Comment: its for Ubuntu OS

Comment: I mean Ubuntu 18.04 19.04 19.10 which one.. because taking that ISO and customize it will be good other than doing it for different one while trying..

Comment: i looking for both ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04

Comment: Hi did you choose any grub theme and splash theme? I will do it for 18.04 if you provide link to  your chosen themes.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot expose the themes to the public. If you can share a document or customization link. i will try out.